# How to link to the mobile version of Google Plus

Tags: mobile, google-plus

We are building a mobile version of our website and in the process of working on our footer's social links, I am stumbling with the Google Plus.

It has been quite easy to convert the FB and Twitter links to be directed at their mobile version (m.facebook.com/ourpage and mobile.twitter.com/ourpage), but I will be darn if I can sort this out for GooglePlus.

I have tried simply going there with my mobile phone browser, but it generates a huge string which seems to be unrelated to our G+ id number.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take `https://plus.google.com/app/basic/` and add the profile/page id.

Google: https://plus.google.com/app/basic/116899029375914044550

<del>Google: https://m.google.com/app/plus/mp/960/#~loop:view=profile&a=g%3A116899029375914044550</del>

I don't think this URL is officially supported by Google so it could change in the future and break your link.

Comment: Thanks.  I did some experimenting with it and the /mp/960 are visitor related, as every time I tried it, it would change these to different number, same as I would get visiting my personal profile.  I did discover that the /mp/960 could be eliminated with the same results.

Comment: Looks like it's broken now